# ListView in android 5.0 settings screen

Tags: android, listview

How do i implement the listView which is in the android 5.0 settings screen in my project.I searched a lot and found no reasonable answers.Any help is appreciated

Comment: your question is unclear

Comment: The listView in the settings screen,with the icon and text in each element.I want to know how to implement that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for PreferenceScreen. Its quite easy to implement it. Have fun.